# Why I can send data from TCP Client to Server, but not vice versa?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, firewall

I wrote an asynchronous TCP server-client in C#. Both programs run successfully when I test them in one computer (server and client run simultaneously in the same machine). But when tested in two different computers, server-client connection is established and the client is able to send data to server, but the server seems to be not sending anything to its client.

By using TCPView, I know that both server and client is receiving/sending data as expected. I thought it was firewall blocking them, I've disabled it and no use. What's wrong with my code?

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

// Server code
namespace ChatConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket serverSocket, clientSocket;
        static byte[] buffer;
        const int defaultBufferSize = 1024;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is server.");

                // Create a new server socket.
                serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Create IP End Point.
                IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1001);

                // Bind endpoint to socket.
                serverSocket.Bind(ep);

                // Start listening for incoming client.
                serverSocket.Listen(4);

                // Execute callback method when client request connection.
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);

                while (true) { }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("from Main(): " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Store client socket handle.
                clientSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Client {0} joined.", clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint);

                // Welcome the client when connection established.
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello from server!");
                clientSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);

                // Begin receiving data from  connected client.
                buffer = new byte[1024];
                clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("from AcceptCallback(): " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Terminate current send session.
            clientSocket.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Replied.");
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Store the length of received data.
                int received = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
                if (received == 0)
                    return;

                // Convert the received data to string then print in the console.
                Array.Resize<byte>(ref buffer, received);
                string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine(text);
                Array.Resize<byte>(ref buffer, defaultBufferSize);

                // Send back message from the client.
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("from server: " + text);
                clientSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);

                clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("from ReceiveCallback(): " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

// Client code
namespace ChatConsoleClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket clientSocket;
        static IPEndPoint ep;
        static byte[] buffer;
        const int defaultBufferSize = 1024;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is client.");

                // Create new socket for client.
                clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Ask for server IP address.
                string IP = Console.ReadLine();

                // Create endpoint to be connected.
                ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 1001);

                // Start connecting to the server.
                clientSocket.BeginConnect(ep, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), null);
                buffer = new byte[1024];

                clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);

                while (true)
                {
                    string text = Console.ReadLine();
                    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

                    clientSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("from Main(): " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            int received = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (received == 0)
                return;

            // Convert the received data to string then print in the console.
            Array.Resize<byte>(ref buffer, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Array.Resize<byte>(ref buffer, defaultBufferSize);
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            clientSocket.EndSend(ar);
        }

        private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            clientSocket.EndConnect(ar);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked client and server running in two different systems but both of them  having the same IP series and it works

Comment: Did you get hello from server message?

Comment: yes , may be in your case please check that firewall blocks server ports